# How to delete a polygon after drawing the second polygon

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

I found a function that draws polygons, but I need it when drawing the second polygon, that it would always delete the previous polygon, since there must always be one polygon on my map

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Draw Features</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/build/ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<form class="form-inline">
  <label>Geometry type &nbsp;</label>
  <select id="type">
    <option value="Box">Box</option>
    <option value="None">None</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

which contains all the html and javascript code
http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/c4o4put8/

[Link to `JS` code](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/c4o4put8/)

Comment: I tried your fiddle; it doesn't draw any polygons. Post a working sample of your code, something that demonstrates the problem. Also, single-step through your code with a debugger. If you still can't find the problem, come back here and discuss your debugging results, along with a code sample that runs and demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Because the code is too large, I sent the link 
which contains all the html and javascript code http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/c4o4put8/

Comment: As I said before, single-step through your code with a debugger. If you still can't find the problem, come back here and discuss your debugging results.

Comment: In my example, there are no errors, my question, if you read, is that I want to delete the rendered layer if I draw the next polygon, line, point

Comment: Here's how StackOverflow works, if you read. You don't come here asking for help with something until you have tried to take care of it yourself. Then when you do come asking for help, you must show what you've tried, and you must discuss why your attempts don't work. As in, what you found out from the debugger.

Comment: I tried quite a few different options, since I write here, which means it was a problem for me

Comment: There is a reason that no one has answered your question. If you read, you will find the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for posting a good question.

Comment: You need to be less clever, I was given an answer, so keep your advice at yourself

Comment: Stubborn, uncooperative, lazy people who flout the rules sometimes get lucky. I'm glad someone finally felt sorry for you.

Comment: I'm glad that you can assert yourself with such primitive statements

Comment: I'm sad that you are incapable of gratitude toward someone who came back numerous times to offer you helpful advice. As I say, you got lucky. Often, badly constructed, rule-breaking questions such as yours get deleted by the moderators. But we shouldn't argue. I will forget all of your rudeness and stubbornness, and I will pretend that you have finished our conversation properly, by **thanking** me for going so far out of my way to **help** you, despite your bad attitude. You are quite welcome. I'm glad to have helped you to learn how to behave in this forum.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `drawstart` event on draw interaction.
2. Use `clear` for source when `drawstart`.

You can access the features on the map through `source` of `layer`.
with your example on the fiddle, your features are contained in variable `vector`. and, as you see your code a while, there's `drawend` event on `draw` interaction which let you guess there's `drawstart` event as well.

```
// just like `drawend`
draw.on('drawstart', function(e) {

});
```

The thing you want is no feature displays when you start drawing so you can clear all feature on the source when `drawstart`

```
// map.getLayers().getArray()[1] is your vector layer
draw.on('drawstart', function(e) {
  map.getLayers().getArray()[1].getSource().clear();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c4o4put8/25/

Comment: Yes, but with this code, I can not get the coordinates of the mouse through alert(e.feature.getGeometry().getExtent());

Comment: You may want to use `e.feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()` instead `e.feature.getGeometry().getExtent()`.